# Como fazer mudanças de um usuario com o metodo PUT no SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Estou fazendo um projeto e estamos na camada de APIs com SpringBoot.
Estamos com problema no verbo PUT. Temos os campos Id, Nome, senha, TipoUsuario, senha, até ai tudo bem, estamos fazendo um If para que ele identifique se existe um usuario existente com aquele nome antes de atualizar, mas o nosso if não deixa alterar a mesma pessoa informando que já existe um usuario com o mesmo nome.

EX: quero alterar o TipoUsuario chamando pelo id sem alterar o nome da pessoa porém ele diz que não posso fazer pois já existe alguém com o mesmo nome.

```
@PutMapping("/atualizar")
public ResponseEntity<Usuario> Put(@RequestBody Usuario usuario) {
    Optional<Usuario> user = usuarioService.AtualizarUsuario(usuario);
    try {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(user.get());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
    }

}
```

Aqui esta o meu PUT de atualizar

Desculpe se não ficou claro é a primeira vez que posto uma duvida

Aqui está o usuarioService

```
package com.proagro.madeInRoca.service;
```

import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.apache.tomcat.util.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.proagro.madeInRoca.model.UserLogin;
import com.proagro.madeInRoca.model.Usuario;
import com.proagro.madeInRoca.repository.UsuarioRepository;

@Service
public class UsuarioService {

```
@Autowired
private UsuarioRepository repository;

public Optional<Usuario> CadastrarUsuario(Usuario usuario){

    if(repository.findByUsuario(usuario.getUsuario()).isPresent()) {
        return null;
    }

    BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    String senhaEconder = encoder.encode(usuario.getSenha());

    usuario.setSenha(senhaEconder);

    return Optional.of(repository.save(usuario));
}

public Optional<Usuario> AtualizarUsuario(Usuario usuario){

    BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    String senhaEconder = encoder.encode(usuario.getSenha());

    usuario.setSenha(senhaEconder);

    return Optional.of(repository.save(usuario));
}

public Optional<UserLogin> Logar(Optional <UserLogin> user){

    BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    Optional <Usuario> usuario = repository.findByUsuario(user.get().getUsuario());

    if(usuario.isPresent()) {
        if(encoder.matches(user.get().getSenha(), usuario.get().getSenha())) {

            String auth = user.get().getUsuario()+":"+user.get().getSenha();
            byte[]encodedAuth=Base64.encodeBase64(auth.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")));
            String authHeader="Basic " + new String (encodedAuth);

            user.get().setToken(authHeader);
            user.get().setNome(usuario.get().getNome());
            user.get().setSenha(usuario.get().getSenha());
            user.get().setTipoUsuario(usuario.get().getTipoUsuario());

            return user;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Cade o código do usuarioService?

Comment: ` public Optional<Usuario> AtualizarUsuario(Usuario usuario){

 BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
 String senhaEconder = encoder.encode(usuario.getSenha());

 usuario.setSenha(senhaEconder);

 return Optional.of(repository.save(usuario));
} `

Comment: Posta o erro do spring quando tenta alterar

Comment: Edita o post e coloca a parte toda do usuarioService relacionada ao update. Só com isso não tá dando pra ver o problema.

Comment: @FranklinBarreto Alteirei o código, coloquei o usuario service

Comment: Aparentemente o que está acontecendo é que ele não está atualizando e sim tentando criar um registro novo. Quando a gente vai fazer um update, tem que passar o id do objeto e buscar ele no banco para que seja gerenciado pela JPA. Se não tiver ficado claro me avisa que posto um código pra você entender.

Comment: @FranklinBarreto Entendi, então seria um findAll ?? Pode me enviar o código se possivel ? Acho que não ficou claro

Comment: @FranklinBarreto Obrigada pela ajuda, conseguimos resolver com o seu codigo.

Comment: @Heloisa seria legal então marcar com útil a resposta (:

Comment: @FranklinBarreto ainda não sei mexer direito, só confirma para mim se eu marquei corretamente por favor?

Comment: Sim sim @Heloisa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1° não é uma boa prática trafegar as suas entidades, mas vamos deixar isso pra depois.
Você tá querendo fazer um update, mas não está buscando um objeto gerenciado pela jpa.
Seu código deve ficar mais ou menos assim.

```
@PutMapping("/atualizar/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Usuario> Put(@RequestBody Usuario usuario, @PathVariable Long id) {
Usuario usuarioSalvo = usuarioService.findById(id).orlElseThrow(()-> new RuntimeExpection("Usuário não existe")); 
// Aqui você faz um mapeamento do que veio para o que já existe setando os dados e ai passa pro seu service mas eu colocaria a lógica no service e não aqui, foi só pra exemplificar
Optional<Usuario> user = usuarioService.AtualizarUsuario(usuario);
   try {
       return ResponseEntity.ok(user.get());
   } catch (Exception e) {
    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
}

}
```

Quando você busca no banco, o JPA vai saber que esse cara existe e ele estará em um estado management e quando você passar ele para o repository.save ele saberá que já existe e irá atualizar ao invés de criar outro.